# I have a colum with a list of different labels and i want to indicate if that label is present with a value of one in the column of the value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, for-loop

For example i have:

```
asd = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                   "B": [[1,2], [1], [1,3], [1]],
                   '1': [0,0,0,0],
                   '2':[0,0,0,0],
                   '3':[0,0,0,0]})
```

and i want to put a number 1 in the columns '1','2' and '3' if that number is in the list on column 'B'. Something like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({"A": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                   "B": [[1,2], [1], [1,3], [1]],
                   '1': [1,1,1,1],
                   '2':[1,0,0,0],
                   '3':[0,0,1,0]})
```

[photo of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJJ1e.png)

I've been trying with for loops but i can't get it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since the names of columns 1, 2, 3 are of string type, and the type of values from the list of column 'B' is numeric.

```
print(type(asd.columns[2]))#<class 'str'>

print(type(asd.loc[0, 'B'][0]))#<class 'int'>
```

I changed the type of column names.

```
asd.rename(columns = {'1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3}, inplace = True )
```

Then, in the list comprehension, the necessary values are simply filled in through the function.

```
def f(x):
    asd.loc[x, asd.loc[x, 'B']] = 1


[f(x) for x in range(len(asd['B']))]

print(asd)
```

Output

```
   A       B  1  2  3
0  a  [1, 2]  1  1  0
1  b     [1]  1  0  0
2  c  [1, 3]  1  0  1
3  d     [1]  1  0  0
```